# What's the difference between "*" and "?" in php preg match?

Tags: php, regex

Is there a difference between using "*" or "?" in php preg_match ? or Is there an example ?

```
<?php

// the string to match against
$string = 'The cat sat on the matthew';

// matches the letter "a" followed by zero or more "t" characters
echo preg_match("/at*/", $string);

// matches the letter "a" followed by a "t" character that may or may not be present
echo preg_match("/at?/", $string);
```

Comment: The comments in your code already describe the difference.

Comment: @GregHewgill  With preg_match, function will stop after the first match, so both ? and * will stop after first match in exact same point and returns "1". What is the difference ?

Comment: @GregHewgill kind of, except that they don't explain why in this case the two behave identically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*` matches 0 or more

`?` matches 0 or 1

In the context of your particular tests you can't tell the difference because the `*` and `?` matches aren't anchored or don't have anything following them - they'll both match any string that contains an `a`, whether followed by a `t` or not.

The difference matters if you had something *after* the match character, e.g.:

```
echo preg_match("/at*z/", "attz"); // true
echo preg_match("/at?z/", "attz"); // false - too many "t"s
```

whereas with yours:

```
echo preg_match("/at*/", "attz"); // true - 0 or more
echo preg_match("/at?/", "attz"); // true - but it stopped after the
                                  // first "t" and ignored the second
```

Comment: although not specifically in the question, buy may lead to some confusion, don't forget about ? as a non-greedy operator like `.*?`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn sure, but in that context it's a modifier, not a match operator in its own right.

Comment: I'm aware, just showing that there is more than one use for `?`. If later someone saw `.*?` they might get confused thinking it means any one char, 0 or more, 0 or 1.

Answer (score 3):

```
// matches the letter "a" followed by zero or more "t" characters

// matches the letter "a" followed by a "t" character that may or may not be present
```

source: [You](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9040435/30018)

Comment: i had to thumb up your answer... :)